# After I launched a new theme , the site always pop up Login form at the foreground

Tags: database, wordpress, authentication, wordpress-theming, themes

I changed the theme of my site today . But here comes a big problem , it always pop up a signin form whenever people visit my site , as you can see it when you visit my site ( http://www.hermoart.com) or you can see the picture below, what is the problem of this , I don’t want this show up to my customers . I need help , thank you guys so so much
[image]

Comment: Looks like you have a htpassword file. It must be at the root of your wordpress and is independant of your theme. Delete this file via FTP and your popup should go away.

Comment: My dear friend , thank you so  so much , god bless you . I will try it up